# Reduce Thread Number when Client Left

Tags: python, sockets

I created a server code to establish connection between multiple clients. When a client connected, a new thread will start to identify the client number. However when a client left, the thread number should reduce by 1 as it indicates the client number has reduced, but unfortunately, i encountered some problems in reducing thread number.

Here is my server code:
My thread number = ThreadCount

```
import socket
import os
from _thread import *

ServerSocket = socket.socket()
host = ''
port = 1233
ThreadCount = 0
try:
    ServerSocket.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print('Waitiing for a Connection..')
ServerSocket.listen(5)


def threaded_client(connection):
    connection.send(str.encode('Welcome to the Server\n'))

    ClientNo = " You are Client:" + str(ThreadCount)
    connection.sendall(str.encode(ClientNo))
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        data1 = data.decode('utf-8')
        reply = 'Server Says: ' + data1
        if (data1 == "exit"):
            print("One Client is left" + str(ThreadCount))
            break
        connection.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    connection.close()

while True:
    Client, address = ServerSocket.accept()
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (Client,))
    ThreadCount += 1
    print('Connected to: ' + address[0] + ':' + str(address[1]) + " | Thread: " + str(ThreadCount) + " | Client: " + str(ThreadCount))

ServerSocket.close()
```

This is the response: When the client left, the threadcount still the same as 2.
[image]

As I try to reduce the threadcount, it shows error like this:
[image]

How can solve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using websockets? Supports asyncio thus it handles threads by default. And doing registration is easy with it. https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#registration It is widely used and runs very robust.

Comment: Yeah, I am required to use only socket.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because ThreadCount is a global variable. The statement tries to make a local variable and reference it in the same line, so it complains. Try doing `global ThreadCount` on the line before, or at the top of the function. That will make the reference global.

Comment: On a complete tangent, it seems on some platforms or tools (I'm on mac using netcat) the socket receive or the decode function reads a newline when I sent it. I would recommend doing `data1 = data.decode('utf-8').strip()` if you find this issue.

Comment: Could i know what the meaning of .strip?